# How to rotate background keeping container fixed?

Tags: css, css-transforms

This is my HTML code:

```
<style>
#myelement
{
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(30deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(30deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(30deg);
    transform: rotate(30deg);
       border:#000000 solid 2px;
       width:500px;
       height:500px;
}

#myelement:before
{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 200%;
    height: 200%;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    z-index: -1;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-30deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-30deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-30deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-30deg);
    transform: rotate(-30deg);

    background: url(image.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat;
}
</style>


<div id="myelement"></div>
```

This is image.jpg file:

[image]

This is output of browser:

[image]

Here, background image is fixed and container is rotating. I want to make reverse. i,e Container will be fixed and background will rotate.

Comment: Why not remove the rotate on parent and keep it only on the child?

Comment: I see, I have gotten my answer. It is due to mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question properly, you only need to apply `transform: rotate` on the pseudo-element which has the background and nothing on the container (like in the below snippet).

```css
#myelement {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: #000000 solid 2px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
#myelement:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  z-index: -1;
  transform: rotate(30deg);
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/lndoe.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div id="myelement"></div>
```

Comment: @AdamSmith: Sorry mate, I had not noticed your comment before adding the answer.